# tcl - lost trace on a element of tcl ::env array

Tags: tcl

I have recently encountered a some code in my project that deals with the `env` array in tcl.

Basically, there is an initialize function that adds a `write trace` on one of the elements present in the `env`. Later in the processing flow of the same use case , there is an `array get ::env` being called that seems to remove the trace that was added.

I tried to replicate the same use case with a normal tcl array and it works fine and the trace that I added still remains even after doing an `array get arrayName` on it. I suspect that something is calling an `unset` on the concerned element. Hence I did put another `unset` trace on it and tried to print the callstack in the function attached to this trace. Unfortunately though, it doesn't print anything helpful.

Am I missing anything that I should be knowing here ? If not, could you please help me suggest what more can I do to debug this ? Just to summarize, I am writing the steps of this use case. I am a newbie with tcl and could do with some help here

```
#add a trace on one of the elements present in env
trace variable ::env(myVar) w myFunction

#get the contents of env 
array get ::env

#trace is lost after the second step,can check by below command
trace vinfo ::env(myVar)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must be using Tcl 8.5 or before. In those versions, the `::env` array was special in that it would be destroyed and recreated frequently because of the complexity of tracking the system environment. This was a bug because it caused all sorts of problems, particularly with `upvar`s to *elements* of `::env` (as opposed to the whole array) and traces (which you've observed for yourself).

In 8.6 (at least by 8.6.8; I forget exactly when the bugfix went in) we changed this to assume that the environment isn't altered underneath our feet all the time (because that's actually true in practice) and variable trace and upvar'd variables are correctly maintained from there on. The core underlying change is that the environment array is updated more carefully, and the `Tcl_Var` structures inside it aren't anything like as ephemeral as they were.

```
$ tclsh8.5
% trace variable ::env(myVar) w myFunction
% array get env
# ... blah blah ...
% trace vinfo ::env(myVar)
```

```
$ tclsh8.6
% trace variable ::env(myVar) w myFunction
% array get env
# ... blah blah ...
% trace vinfo ::env(myVar)
{w myFunction}
```

In short, ***fix by upgrading to Tcl 8.6.***

Comment: Woah ! An answer from one of the core members . That certainly helps :) I shall try this and let you know for sure . Thanks a ton .

PS : I just printed the version of tcl we are using and it is indeed 8.5  

`(win64d) 161 % puts $tcl_version`
8.5

Comment: It may also be wise to switch to the current way of doing traces. The subcommands you used are "deprecated and will likely be removed in a future version of Tcl", as the manual page says.

Comment: @SchelteBron thanks for the suggestion. I will definitely take it into account and arrive at a final solution.